# collision for two round objects javascript / html canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, collision-detection

I have been researching but I find it so hard to find a code or function to detect collision between two circles basically .

I used the code for how I would normally check detection but obviously at an angle it will detect collision when it should not.

```
    if (
      (
        covid19Obj.x + covid19Obj.width < secondObj.x ||
        covid19Obj.x > secondObj.x + secondObj.width ||
        covid19Obj.y > secondObj.y + secondObj.height  ||
        covid19Obj.y + covid19Obj.height < secondObj.y
      )
    ) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection

Comment: how would i find the radius through javascript? do i just add another property ?